# About the missing Rainbow Splash

Tags: pi-4

guys. Im not sure whether my Rpi4B is going wrong. I dont see the rainbow splash when I boot every time.
At first I see the black screen with cursor, then the raspberry pic appears in a very short time. After that, the moitor will turn off for one second and then turn on. Finally I will see the desktop.
But I want to see the rainbow splash at the very beginning.
My RaspberryPi is model 4B with the latest Raspbian OS released on April, 2022.

Comment: Try booting the latest 2022-04-04 RaspiOS Bullseye *LITE* that has the rainbow screen when I boot it.

Comment: The black screen w/ cursor is after the splash, which unless boot fails is gone pretty quickly -- this may just have to do with your monitor initializing when the first signal is received.  It's not meant as a normal splash, I think.  It's just what the GPU throws up when the first bit of firmware loads, to help in debugging boot failures.  You could check to see whether `disable_splash` is set in `/boot/config.txt`.